# x.y Activity is not a concrete class error message in manifest

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

[image]

I got ... **"is not a concrete class"** error in manifest file.

The app works though. I can build and test without problem but this error bugs my eyes. Please help if you can.

When **I ctrl + click on the activity name on the manifest it even opens the .java src file.**

(The activity is actually called "MapInputActivty" - typo i know, but this is not the problem.)

Comment: Is `MapInputActivty` an abstract class that other Activities are extending?

Comment: can u post  MapInputActivity you missed to implement some methods of interface probably?

Comment: did you implement any interface in MapInputActivty? Did you override all methods of that interface?

Comment: @MikeM Yes it is. Should i remove it from manifest then?

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to list it in the manifest. Just the concrete subclasses that will actually run.

Comment: @MikeM. If you post this as an answer i'll accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That message is telling you that the `MapInputActivty` class is `abstract`, and instantiation will fail should the system try to launch it. The base classes for your app's components don't need to appear in the manifest. Only the concrete subclasses are necessary, so that the system has the appropriate information on the components' capabilities and functionalities. For example, though all of your Activities must be descendents of the `Activity` class, you wouldn't list the `Activity` class in the manifest.